# What is the smallest subset of C that modern compilers can optimise as well as C?

Tags: c, code-generation

I want to generate some C and verify that it will compile and so I want to use a subset of C to make the verification easier.
However I don’t want to limit what can be written so I want a subset of C such that given any C program you can write a program that will compile to the same machine code in a modern compiler.

For example I believe the following constructs to be unnecessary:

- `x++`, `++x`, `x—-`, `—-x`
- (Edit: These are not, thanks to @dmuir and @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica) `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`
- `a[i]`
- Array types outside of declarations
- `p->m`

Are there any more and are any of mine necessary for certain optimisations?

Comment: @StaceyGirl I believe that any modern compiler will generate the same code from `x += y` and `x = x + y` so I am classing `+=` as an unnecessary construct.
In principle I could also remove array declarations in favour of using `malloc` and achieve the same result but this carries a massive performance penalty so I don’t consider them unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not so sure about += etc. Suppose e was a complex expression involving a call of a function that had side effects; then e += 1 would not be the same as e = e + 1, because the side-effects would happen twice in the second form.

Comment: Your belief considers only simple objects as operands. In the case of function calls that are used to produce lvalues, for instance `*f() += 1`. The result will not be the same, because `*f() = *f() + 1` must call the function *twice*, whereas the shorthand calls it only once. That affects the behavior. So it's something to be mindful of.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. A certain feature might be redundant because a similar feature exists functionality-wise, but that doesn't necessarily mean they are equivalent in terms of performance. There's tons of subtle crap like x += y not being exactly the same as x = x + y in terms of evaluation, or ?: not being exactly the same as if-else because of implicit promotions, certain boolean checks being functionally equivalent but one of them generating a branch etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin I had forgotten about `+=` of function calls and stuff, my question was about which are redundant in terms of generated machine code so that would include performance and generating branches but not implicit promotions as they could be written explicitly.

Comment: All operators in C simply have too much subtle crap associated with them... so I think you'd only up with various forms of flow control that are redundant: you don't need goto, continue, switch etc.

Comment: The question is nonsensical. The stated goal, “I want to generate some C and verify that it will compile,” can be accomplished by generating well formed C code and/or by invoking a compiler and evaluating its result. The stated reason “I want to use a subset of C to make the verification easier” does not well support the stated goal. The statement “I don’t want to limit what can be written so I want a subset of C such that given any C program you can write a program that will compile to the same machine code in a modern compiler” is a *non sequitur*. And the latter is essentially impossible.

Comment: The statements “I want to use a subset of C” and “I don’t want to limit what can be written” are contradictory. The place where the question ends, generating identical machine code, has no relation to where it starts, generating code that will compile as C code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I actually want to write in Idris, a dependently typed language, and so verify at compile time that any C code generated will type check.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don’t need to include `a[i]` as a possible C expression as it is exactly equivalent to `*(a + i)` and so my generating code can be simpler

Comment: Ever heard of `C--`? See [C-- homepage](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/c--/index.html) or the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--)

Comment: @pmg Yes, I looked into `C—` but it seems to be designed to be used with a different compiler, not to feed into a standard C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Things you could exclude from the "subset of C" without requiring a difference in the compiler's output include:

- pre-increment and post-increment (`x++`, `++x`).  This includes unusual situations where side-effects would have to be emulated explicitly.
- assignment operators (`x =+ ..`, etc). This includes unusual situations where side-effects would have to be emulated explicitly.
- either array accesses (but not definition of arrays) or `*` as pointer dereference (e.g. `x = *pointer;` replaced by `x = pointer[0];`).
- almost all whitespace (e.g. everything except the newline character), including comments and line continuation (`\` at end of line)
- trigraphs (replaceable by their normal character equivalents)
- `do`, `while` and `for` (all replaceable with `if` and `goto`); but not `switch` (I expect that modern compilers use the `switch` keyword as a "consider conversion into jump table" hint)
- `break;` (can be replaced by `goto`)
- the `inline` keyword (its typically ignored anyway)
- brackets in expressions. These can be eliminated by re-arranging expressions and/or using temporary variables (e.g. `x = (y + z) * 3;` replaced by `temp = y + z; x = temp * 3;`).
- half of the relational operators (e.g. `x = a != b` can be replaced by `x = !(a == b);`, `x = a <= b` can be replaced by `x = !(a > b);`, etc)
- hexadecimal and octal for numerical constants (can replace with decimal constants)
- negation. Can be replaced with subtraction (e.g. `x = -y;` replaced with `x = 0 - y;`)
- either `&` or `|`. Replaced by their equivalent using DeMorgan's laws (e.g. `x = a & b;` replaced with `x = ~(~a | ~b);`).
- either `&&` or `||`. Replaced by their equivalent using DeMorgan's laws (e.g. `if( (a == b) && (c == d) )` replaced with `if( !(a != b) || (c != d) )`).
- comma used as statement separator. Code using comma as a statement separator can always be refactored into code that doesn't (e.g. `for(i = 0, j = 0; i < k; i++, j++) { foo(); }` replaced with `j = 0; for(i = 0; i < k; i++) { foo(); j++; }` or maybe `i = 0; j = 0; if(i < k) goto done; next: ; foo(); i = i + 1; j = j + 1; if( !(i < k)) goto next; done: ; }`.
- `enum`. Can be replaced by a set of `#define ..`.

Note 1: "without requiring a difference in the compiler's output" (in my first sentence) means that there may be a difference in the compiler's output that wasn't required.

Note 2: I would "very much dislike" reading source code that did these things. For source code readability (e.g. debugging the output of your "Idris to C" converter to see if your converter has bugs) I would avoid doing any of the things in this list.

Comment: "the inline keyword (its typically ignored anyway)" - this is wrong, every compiler _does_ use it as a hint. For example in Clang it sets inline threshold to 487 instead of 375 (`-O3`) or 75 (`-Os`).

Comment: `trigraphs` and digraphs `the inline keyword` and `register` and `restrict` (and `auto`, who uses auto).

Comment: @StaceyGirl: See "note 1" about "without requiring a difference".. ;-)

Comment: @Brendan Then I guess you can add `struct`, `union` and `enum` to the list. But I am not sure that this what OP asked for.

Comment: @StaceyGirl: Added `enum`. I can't see what you'd use as an alternative to `struct` (especially if there's bitfields). Using `struct` as an alternative to `union` won't work (unless compiler is able to determine that different fields of the "struct" are never used at the same time and optimize back to "same as union", which is extremely unlikely).

Comment: @Brendan You can just use `char*` and add offsets manually, then cast to the type you need. Basically similar to how early C versions worked when struct members were global (and `struct` was just a syntactic sugar for allocating offsets).

Comment: @StaceyGirl: I think that would break optimizations that rely on strict aliasing rules (would require a difference in compiler's output when compiler thinks that "pointer to struct" has the same type as `char *`)

Comment: @Brendan Same with omitting `inline` - breaks inlining hint and reduces chance of inlining. I am  talking about your "note 1". Compiler is not required to use aliasing rules.

Comment: @StaceyGirl: No, `inline` doesn't require a difference in output while breaking strict aliasing optimizations does require a difference in output.

Comment: @Brendan No it doesn't. Compiler can just assume that every pointer can alias anything e.g. what MSVC does by default and GCC does with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Every optimization is optional.

Comment: @StaceyGirl: And? For GCC with `--fno-strict-aliasing` the output is "required to be different" to what it would've been without `--fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: @Brendan Not if compiler never uses strict aliasing. But I get what you are saying. It just looks to me that OP wants to keep things that are used by the optimizer (and `inline` is one of those things), but throw away everything that does not affect it.